# I need PHP help opening a CSV file into an array, altering the data, and then overwriting the original CSV file with the altered data

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv, preg-split

I need to pull data from a CSV file to use in reporting. However, the exporting software does not have the capability to export it in a useful format. Using PHP I would like to take a CSV file with data like:

```
'Time','Month And Year','Count'
'8 Hours','Apr 2011','127'
'6 Hours','Apr 2011','45'
'4 Hours','Apr 2011','23'
'2 Hours','Apr 2011','122'
'8 Hours','Dec 2010','29'
'6 Hours','Dec 2010','8'
'4 Hours','Dec 2010','1'
'2 Hours','Dec 2010','64'
etc...
```

And turn it into this:

```
Time,Dec 2010,Jan 2011,Feb 2011,Mar 2011,Apr 2011,May 2011
8 Hours,126,47,115,77,127,110
6 Hours,45,18,62,38,42,31
4 Hours,23,3,11,8,15,18
2 Hours,122,93,185,144,128,70
```

At the moment, I have the code to open the CSV file using fgetcsv() and remove unwanted characters:

```
$lines = array();
$tempName = array();
$tempCount = array();
$tempTitle = array();
$items = array();

$fp = fopen('../data/data2.csv','r') or die("can't open data2.csv");

while($lines = fgetcsv($fp,4096,"\\n")) {

  for ($i = 0, $j = count($lines); $i < $j; $i++) {

    $lines[$i] = str_replace('\'', '', $lines[$i]);
    $lines[$i] = str_replace('A: ', '', $lines[$i]);
    $lines[$i] = str_replace('B: ', '', $lines[$i]);
    $lines[$i] = str_replace('C: ', '', $lines[$i]);
    $lines[$i] = str_replace('D: ', '', $lines[$i]);

  }
}

fclose($fp) or die("can't close volume2.csv");
```

This stores the lines of the CSV file into comma delimited rows, which makes the $lines array look like:

```
Time,Month And Year,Count
8 Hours,Apr 2011,127
6 Hours,Apr 2011,45
4 Hours,Apr 2011,23
2 Hours,Apr 2011,122
8 Hours,Dec 2010,29
6 Hours,Dec 2010,8
4 Hours,Dec 2010,1
2 Hours,Dec 2010,64
etc...
```

Now what I need to do is store the data in the correct order inside of one or more arrays in order to be able to export it back into the CSV file.

I tried using:

```
for ($h = 0, $k = count($lines); $h < $k; $h++) {
  $items = preg_split("/[,]+/",$lines[$h]);
}
```

and then placing the correct data into arrays using a case statement, but it hangs up, so I must be doing something wrong. (Not to mention this code is not optimized.)

Any ideas on where I can go from here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `fgetcsv()` in the wrong way and having it read in multiple lines at once.

Modify your code to use:

```
while($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {

}
```

and in each iteration parse a row at a time.

if you want to write this back to a CSV file you shoudl be able to do something like:

```
$out = array();
while($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
    // modify fields as you need to
    $out[] = implode(",", $line);
}

// now you can write implode("\n", $out) out as the modified data
```